# LeakCanary shows leak but not complete stacktrace

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I am using LeakCanary to detect leaks in my app.

In the stack trace it show

```
static hk.a
|
references ht.a
|
leaks TestActivity instance
```

No other information. 
How to get more information to debug the issue?
Thanks

Comment: is proguard on?

Comment: No, proguard is off